# Integrity Error May not be null

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am building a website similar to a bartering website, but we are bartering Time,
I have a class Transaction, where it takes the "offer" value, deductions that value from the balance of the requesting user, and credits the value to the Offer'r.

Right now when I click on "Accept Offer" from my template I get this error

```
ofertoj_transaction.accepted_by may not be NULL
```

Stacktrace:

```
IntegrityError at /oferto/accept/
```

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/oferto/accept/?offer_id=1&creator=2

Django Version: 1.5.4
Python Version: 2.7.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'zinnia',
 'tagging',
 'mptt',
 'south',
 'registration',
 'blogs',
 'turtle',
 'ofertoj',
 'petoj',
 'x',
 'profiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  86.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/talisman/projects/tempilo/ofertoj/views.py" in get
  74.                   accepted_by=self.request.user.id
File "/home/talisman/projects/tempilo/ofertoj/models.py" in create
  59.       new_transaction.save()
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  546.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  650.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  215.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1675.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  937.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  41.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  364.             six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/tempilo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  362.             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /oferto/accept/
Exception Value: ofertoj_transaction.accepted_by may not be NULL
```

## part of ofertoj.views.py

```
class TransactionView(TemplateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    template_name = "ofertoj/offer_accepted.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.GET.get("offer_id"):
            oferto = Oferto.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get("offer_id"))
            if oferto.valid:
                transaction = Transaction()
                transaction.create(
                    creator=self.request.GET.get("creator"),
                    amount=oferto.time,
                    accepted_by=self.request.user.id
                )
                acceptor = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
                acceptor.balance = acceptor.balance - oferto.time
                acceptor.save()

                # credit the coins to the creator
                creator = Profile.objects.get(user=oferto.user)
                creator.balance = creator.balance + oferto.time
                creator.save()
            else:
                return HttpResponse("This offer is already accepted")
        else:
            raise Http404

        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Part of Ofertoj.models

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    creator = models.IntegerField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    accepted_by = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        new_transaction = Transaction(
                creator = kwargs['creator'],
                amount = kwargs['amount'],
                accepted_by = kwargs['accepted_by']
            )
        new_transaction.save()
        return
```

this line is highlited in the stacktrace

```
acceptor = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

## ofertoj.urls

```
url(
    regex=r"^accept/$",
    view = TransactionView.as_view(),
    name = "accept_offer"
    ),
```

part of my template

```
{% if oferto.valid and not oferto.user == request.user %}
<a href="{% url "accept_offer" %}?offer_id={{ oferto.id }}&creator={{ oferto.user.id }}">Accept this Offer</a>
{% endif %}

<br /><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ofertoj` application is trying to store a `Transaction` object which has an `accepted_by` field which is `NULL` but your database schema does not allow this field to be `NULL`.

Check this code:

```
transaction.create(
                creator=self.request.GET.get("creator"),
                amount=oferto.time,
                accepted_by=self.request.user.id
            )
```

and the code of `transaction.create`.

One possibility: if your user is not logged in then `self.request.user.id` will be `None`, and this translates to `NULL` in the database. I do not see anything in your code that requires the user to be logged in.

Comment: I don't want it to be null, I want the logged in user to be the accepted_by

Comment: Yes, I get that you don't want it to be null but somewhere along the line, the data you send to the database makes it so that it is null.

Answer (score 0):

it was an issue with **unicode** method in the Profile model
and since, the balance was default null